# Incremental SQLite <-> MySQL replication Android

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, synchronization

I have a SQLite database on Android, which I'm designing to be available offline, and is getting data through a REST API on the server side. But is there any way I can only get the data that has changed since last upload? For example, if there is 5 customers registered in the MySQL database, and one of them change the address, then I only want to update the one with new address, and not the other 4.

Comment: SQLite has something called "online backup api", I've never messed with it but it might help your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using timestamp field will be a solution for downloading incremental changes from the server to the client. For uploading data from the client to the server - some "Dirty" flag can be used to designate new records for upload.

Have a look at this question: [Client-server synchronization over REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18750301/client-server-synchronization-over-rest/18763546#18763546), which addresses the similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

There is no build in API.

However you can create a timestamp column for every table which gets set on every update and insert.
When syncing, you can ask the server to give you only the rows with a timestamp greater than the last sync.

You might get in trouble when doing updates in both directions.